# PostgreSQL 10 not able to start on Mac

Tags: postgresql

I'm running PostgreSQL 10 on a mac running macOS Mojave 10.14.1, i'm getting a could not start PostgreSQL server, pg_ctl could not start server.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CyhA0.png)

and the log shows: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yXzt.png)

-LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432

-LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432

-LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"

-LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-05-28 21:53:17 EDT

-LOG:  invalid record length at 0/18B6A00: wanted 24, got 0

-LOG:  invalid primary checkpoint record

-LOG:  invalid record length at 0/18B6920: wanted 24, got 0

-LOG:  invalid secondary checkpoint record

-PANIC:  could not locate a valid checkpoint record

-LOG:  startup process (PID 3462) was terminated by signal 6: Abort trap

-LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure

-LOG:  database system is shut down

Just wondering if anyone has seen something similar to this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database or wal are corrupted. Normally it could fix itself unless it is very bad. Is it a new database? If so, delete it and recreate.

Comment: I had postgreSql running but removed it and just threw it back on as a new installation. What would i have to do to throw make it functional again? Is there a way to start with a new wal

Comment: I could not fix corrupted wal. Wal is compared with the database and deleted, unless it is something very wrong. Is it a new database?  If so, recreate a new one. If not, do you have a recent backup?  If it is yes,  then restore it.

Comment: i'm acutally just opening it there are no databases yet

Comment: Then follow any postgresql tutorial to create a database from template.